In asp.net core Blazer server side with Windows authentication, how do I use an Active Directory user group to secure a page?
I created a default project using Blazer server side with Windows authentication. In the Program.cs I created a policy for the Domain Users group. This is the same policy that worked in an asp.net core MVC application, however the policy does not work in Blazer. The authentication is working and I can see my Active Directory username and all my claims for all the users groups I am in. I also tried using a policy based on policy using the SID of an AD group, but that did not work ether.
This is the same policy that worked in an asp.net core MVC
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("DomainUsers", policy => policy.RequireRole(@"xyz\Domain Users"));
});


I also tried using a policy based on policy using the SID of an AD group, but that did not work ether.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("DomainUsers", policy => 
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, 
        "S-1-5-21-448359723-410327232-725345543-721"));
});


@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>
<AuthorizeView Policy="DomainUsers">
<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}


